# Bootstrap Dropdown Not Working (Answers to other similar questions not working!)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I know this question has been asked before, however, none of the answers have seemed to prove to work.

I've worked out a nav-menu in bootstrap with a dropdown, pretty much copied from the example. However, when I click on the dropdown, nothing happens. I've included a link to JQuery, included the bootstrap CSS / JS links through CDN, and nothing is working. I've also made sure to put the JQuery before the bootstrap.

I've also tried removing the !-- OPTIONAL THEME bootstrap link (as some people have said multiple bootstrap links have caused issues..) ... but nothing.

Could any of this be because I'm running it on a localsever? I'm doubtful of that...

Let me know what you think! Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="normalize.css"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<header>
<div class="container">
<div class="row>">
<div class="col-xl-12">
  <img class="logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/HSF.png">
  <h1 class="title">TITLE</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="fwcnav" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Emerge</a>
  </div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="fwcnav">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current) </span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Little Ones</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Workout With Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Workouts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Join A Challenge Group</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so I found I also had a  section in my index.php with a link to my stylesheet. I got rid of that, along with getting rid of my stylesheet link in my header.php, and the code worked fine. I put my link back to my style.css in my header, and it screwed up again. So, I'm guessing something in my CSS is making this code mess up?

Here's my style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: Title
Theme URI: Title
Description: X
Version: 1.0
Author: Author
Author URI: Website
*/

/* HEADER & NAVIGATION */

header {
    background-color: rgb(20,20,20);
      }

h1.title {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
    color: #f63a84;
}

/* BODY */

body {
    background-color: rgb(20,20,20);
 }

a {
    color: #f63a84;
    font-family: serif;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

a.button {
-webkit-appearance: button;
-moz-appearance: button;
appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none;
height: 60px;
width: 400px;
font-size: 2em;
background-color: #f63a84; 
color: white;
border: 2px solid black;
}

a.button2 {
-webkit-appearance: button;
-moz-appearance: button;
appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none;
height: 60px;
width: 400px;
font-size: 1.5em;
background-color: #f63a84; 
color: white;
border: 2px solid black;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #f63a84;
    font-style: bold;
}

img.logo {
float: right;
width: 175px;
height: 175px;
padding-top: 0px;
}

/* NAVIGATION */

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
}

/* CONTENT */

article {
    max-width: 950px;
    padding: 20px 0 100px 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

article.home {
    padding: 20px 0 100px 0;
margin-left: 0px;
}

article.other {
    padding: 20px 0 100px 0;
margin-left: 0px;
}

article.blog-article {
    max-width: 950px;
    padding: 20px 0 50px 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
margin-top: 0px;
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
font-family: serif;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: rgb(248,248,248);
padding: 0 0 0 45px;
  }

button {
height: 60px;
width: 400px;
font-size: 2em;
background-color: #f63a84;; 
color: white;
border: 2px solid black;
}

.button:hover {
background-color: white;
color: #f63a84;
}

/* FOOTER */

footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* MEDIA RESPONSIVENESS */

@media (max-width: @screen-xl) {
h1.title {font-size: 1em;}
}
```

Comment: any clue from browser's console?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Inspect element? View source?

Comment: worksout
join a channel group dropdown? it works at my place

Comment: https://snag.gy/GL7jxJ.jpg , im using ur code and it works

Answer (score -1):

Try this it will work

```css
header {
    background-color: rgb(20,20,20);
      }

h1.title {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
    color: #f63a84;
}

/* BODY */

body {
    background-color: rgb(20,20,20);
 }

a {
    color: #f63a84;
    font-family: serif;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

a.button {
-webkit-appearance: button;
-moz-appearance: button;
appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none;
height: 60px;
width: 400px;
font-size: 2em;
background-color: #f63a84; 
color: white;
border: 2px solid black;
}

a.button2 {
-webkit-appearance: button;
-moz-appearance: button;
appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none;
height: 60px;
width: 400px;
font-size: 1.5em;
background-color: #f63a84; 
color: white;
border: 2px solid black;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #f63a84;
    font-style: bold;
}

img.logo {
float: right;
width: 175px;
height: 175px;
padding-top: 0px;
}

/* NAVIGATION */

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
}

/* CONTENT */

article {
    max-width: 950px;
    padding: 20px 0 100px 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

article.home {
    padding: 20px 0 100px 0;
margin-left: 0px;
}

article.other {
    padding: 20px 0 100px 0;
margin-left: 0px;
}

article.blog-article {
    max-width: 950px;
    padding: 20px 0 50px 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
margin-top: 0px;
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
font-family: serif;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: rgb(248,248,248);
padding: 0 0 0 45px;
  }

button {
height: 60px;
width: 400px;
font-size: 2em;
background-color: #f63a84;; 
color: white;
border: 2px solid black;
}

.button:hover {
background-color: white;
color: #f63a84;
}

/* FOOTER */

footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* MEDIA RESPONSIVENESS */

@media (max-width: @screen-xl) {
h1.title {font-size: 1em;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"             href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">       </script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100|Luckiest+Guy|Quicksand:300|Asap:700|Montserrat:700|Open+Sans|Roboto|Signika:700" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="container">
<div class="row>">
<div class="col-xl-12">
  <img class="logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/HSF.png">
  <h1 class="title">TITLE</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fwcnav" aria-expanded="true">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Emerge</a>
  </div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="fwcnav">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current) </span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Little Ones</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Workout With Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Workouts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Join A Challenge Group</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Following are the changes that you need to make---

1. use `data-target="#fwcnav" aria-expanded="true"` instead of `data-target="fwcnav" aria-expanded="false"`
2. Try using my `CDN s`.

I have included the working example.

**EDIT**

I edited the code snippet and used your CSS. It seems to work fine(*The dropdown*).
Check out the working snippet.

So, according to me there must be some problem with your include path. Check whether you are adding the the CSS file twice or not. That is you are including the style sheet in the `index.php` and as well as in the `header.php`.Try removing one of them, Sometimes it causes the problem.

Comment: Ok, I agree! I ran the code on my own in the W3 try it and it worked fine. I got rid of the link to my own style sheet on my local host, but that didn't help. Still not working. SOOO, I think it must be something on my index.php or footer php that's making the dropdown not work in the header? Any ideas?

Comment: Check my edit to my main question, please! Must be something with my stylesheet...